# Test class For http Post

Tags: apex, rest-api, httppost

i wrote unit test code and got 52% code coverage and struck with following error:

> System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object.

Please correct me where i wrong i am new tp apex and rest api.

```
@isTest
public class LeadCreateTest {

    static testmethod void teste(){

        Lead ll1= new Lead();
        ll1.FirstName ='Test';
        ll1.LastName='LeadLastName';
        ll1.CMS_ID__c='12345';
        ll1.Company='ABC';
        insert ll1;
        List<Addresses__c> addressToBeInsertedList = new List<Addresses__c>();
        fromJSON.cls_Addresses ll2 = new fromJSON.cls_Addresses();
        // ll2.Lead__c     = ll1.id;
        ll2.CMS_Id   = ll1.CMS_ID__c;
        ll2.city  = 'pune';
        Addresses__c address = new Addresses__c();
        address.CMS_ADDRESS_ID__c =   ll2.CMS_Id;
        address.Lead__c = ll1.Id;
       addressToBeInsertedList.add(address);
        insert address;
        RestRequest request = new RestRequest();
        request.requestUri ='/services/apexrest/something';
        request.httpMethod = 'POST';
        String myJSON = JSON.serializePretty(address);
        request.requestBody = Blob.valueof(myJSON);
        RestContext.request = request;
        String accObj = CreateLead.doPost();

    }

}
```

Here is doPost mehthod code:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/something/*')
global with sharing class CreateLead 
{  
    @HttpPost
    global static string doPost() 
    {
        String errorMsg = '';
        List<Addresses__c> addressToBeInsertedList = new List<Addresses__c>();
        RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
        Blob body = req.requestBody;
        String requestString = body.toString();     
        fromJSON request = fromJSON.parse(requestString);   

        Lead lead = new Lead();
        lead.FirstName = request.FirstName;
        lead.LastName = request.LastName;
        lead.State = 'New';
        lead.CMS_ID__c = request.CMS_ID;
        lead.Company = request.Company;
        lead.Email =  request.Email;    
        lead.Phone =  request.Phone;    
        lead.Status = request.Status;   
        lead.Company = request.Company; 
        lead.Salutation =  request.Salutation;
        lead.isStaff__c = String.isBlank(request.isStaff)?false:Boolean.valueOf(request.isStaff);   
        lead.Joined_Date__c = String.isBlank(request.Joined_Date)?null: Date.valueOf(request.Joined_Date);  
        lead.SAP_Code__c =  request.SAP_Code;   
        lead.isSuperuser__c =String.isBlank(request.isSuperuser)?false:Boolean.valueOf(request.isSuperuser);    
        try
        {
            insert lead;
        }Catch(Exception e)
        {
            errorMsg = e.getMessage();
        }

        if(request.Addresses.size() > 0  )
        {
            for(fromJSON.cls_Addresses add : request.Addresses)
            {
                Addresses__c address = new Addresses__c(); // custom object in saleforce
                address.CMS_ADDRESS_ID__c =  add.CMS_Id;    
                address.Street_1__c =  add.Street_1;    
                address.Street_2__c =  add.Street_2;    
                address.State__c =  add.State;  
                address.Country__c =  add.Country;  
                address.Postal_Code__c =  add.Postal_Code;
                address.City__c =  add.City ;
                address.Type__c =  add.Type;
                address.Lead__c = lead.Id;
                addressToBeInsertedList.add(address);
            }
        }
        try
        {
            insert addressToBeInsertedList;
        }Catch(Exception e)
        {
            ErrorMsg = e.getMessage();
        }
        Response resp = new Response();
        if(errorMsg == '')
        {
            resp.Status = 'Success';
            resp.Message = 'Lead and Address Inserted Successfully.';
        }
        else
        {
            resp.Status = 'Error';
            resp.Message = errorMsg;
        }
        return JSON.serialize(resp);
    }  
    public class Response
    {
        Public String Status;
        Public String Message;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to pay attention to the class name and line number reported as part of the `NullPointerException`. That will point you to the exact line where the problem occurs which makes figuring out the problem a whole lot easier.

Comment: i got exception on last line ie.String accObj = CreateLead.doPost();

Comment: @Satish as keith said  whats the line number where the exception is ? you also need to post code of doPost method, just the error message and some test class code wont be of much use

Comment: for(fromJSON.cls_Addresses add : request.Addresses)
        {: from this line i got exception.

Comment: The JSON that you are passing from test class is not in correct format. You will have to correct the JSON format.

Comment: @Vijay Ganji thanks for your valuable response.